# How can I make it really difficult to bot a multiply tetris game?

Tags: javascript

I thought about making a multiplayer tetris game using web technologies. However, as the source code is very public when writing a web-based JavaScript/HTML5 game, it would be fairly simple to program a bot to play a near perfect game. So, how could one make it really difficult to bot a tetris game?

I figured, that I could do something fancy like running the game entirely on a server and stream the game as a video using HTML canvas, but this will still be fairly simple to write a bot for, I would presume.

What sort of thing could I do to make it difficult to write a bot for this game, multiplayer tetris?

Comment: nobody would care to write a bot for a game, unless it provides some rewards for win.

Answer (score 4):

I would write the game first and then worry about bots once **if** it becomes a problem. Worrying about this sort of thing at this early stage may stop you developing the game at all which would be a shame.

I'd love to play the game, and I probably have the skills to write a bot but I wouldn't waste my time.

Comment: I would also recommend the *if you can't beat them, join them* approach. If bots become a problem, create a "bots only" area of the game where people can put their bot against others' bots to see who can write the best one.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a captcha but in the end you can not protect against it if your game is running on the client side. The best solution I know is to make statistics of the users actions. For example bots do react faster, always click on the same position, ...

This way you can detect a lot of bots and place them in a "cheater" highscore. This way they are happy and do not bother normal players.